# How to use the memoir package to make a custom title page

Tags: memoir, titles

There's probably an easy way to do this, but how can I add a memoir title page style to an existing document? I have tried this code, but I still get the basic title page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}  %needs recent version of »titlesec«
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newcommand*{\titleGM}{\begingroup% Gentle Madness
\drop = 0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\vfill
\hbox{%
\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
\rule{1pt}{\textheight}
\hspace*{0.05\textwidth}%
\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{
\vbox{%
\vspace{\drop}
{\noindent\HUGE\bfseries Some\\[0.5\baselineskip]
Conundrums}\\[2\baselineskip]
{\Large\itshape Puzzles for the Mind}\\[4\baselineskip]
{\Large THE AUTHOR}\par
\vspace{0.5\textheight}
{\noindent The Publisher}\\[\baselineskip]
}% end of vbox
}% end of parbox
}% end of hbox
\vfill
\null
\endgroup}

\title{\Huge\textbf{ORTHODOX RULE OF PRAYER}}
\author{\Large\textbf{Father Thomas Moore, Michael Dykes}}
\date{\Large{\today}}

\begin{document}

\title{\Huge\textbf{ORTHODOX RULE OF PRAYER}}
\author{\Large\textbf{Father Thomas Moore, Michael Dykes}}
\date{\Large{\today}}

Towards evening, we stand before the holy icons (having lit a candle and        maybe some incense), with reverence and fear of God; we gather our thoughts, make the        Sign of the Cross, and say:

\end{document}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only need to create the `\drop` length and invoke `\titleGM` in your document (I did two other minor changes, setting the page style to `empty` an changing the height for the rule to prevent an overfull `\vbox`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}  %needs recent version of »titlesec«
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlength\drop
\newcommand*{\titleGM}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup% Gentle Madness
\drop = 0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\vfill
\hbox{%
\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-28pt\relax}%
\hspace*{0.05\textwidth}%
\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{
\vbox{%
\vspace{\drop}
{\noindent\HUGE\bfseries Some\\[0.5\baselineskip]
Conundrums}\\[2\baselineskip]
{\Large\itshape Puzzles for the Mind}\\[.37\baselineskip]
{\Large THE AUTHOR}\par
\vspace{0.5\textheight}
{\noindent The Publisher}\\[\baselineskip]
}% end of vbox
}% end of parbox
}% end of hbox
\vfill
\null
\endgroup}

\title{\Huge\textbf{ORTHODOX RULE OF PRAYER}}
\author{\Large\textbf{Father Thomas Moore, Michael Dykes}}
\date{\Large{\today}}

\begin{document}

\titleGM

Towards evening, we stand before the holy icons (having lit a candle and        maybe some incense), with reverence and fear of God; we gather our thoughts, make the        Sign of the Cross, and say:

\end{document}
```

[image]

To automatically use the information contained in the standard commands `\author`, `\title`, some modification is required:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}  %needs recent version of »titlesec«
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newlength\drop
\newcommand*{\titleGM}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup% Gentle Madness
\drop = 0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\vfill
\hbox{%
  \hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
  \rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-28pt\relax}%
  \hspace*{0.05\textwidth}% 
  \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{%
    \vbox{%
      \vspace{\drop}
      {\Huge\bfseries\raggedright\@title\par}\vskip2.37\baselineskip
      {\Large\bfseries\@author\par}
      \vspace{0.5\textheight}
    }% end of vbox
  }% end of parbox
}% end of hbox
\vfill
\null
\endgroup}
\makeatother

\title{ORTHODOX RULE OF PRAYER}
\author{Father Thomas Moore, Michael Dykes}

\begin{document}

\titleGM

Towards evening, we stand before the holy icons (having lit a candle and        maybe some incense), with reverence and fear of God; we gather our thoughts, make the        Sign of the Cross, and say:

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Whenever I add what yuu said above t my code, I keep getting an error mssg; simply: xdg-open prayerbook.pdf and the document will not open

Comment: Nevermind, now it complies and opens fine! Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: Now, how do I change the title, author, etc to what I have below in \title, \author, etc? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelDykes I updated my answer showing how to automatically include the information for the `\author` and `\title` fields; for the `\date` field, I didn't know where to place this field. Can you please tell me if you want also the date to appear in the titlepage and exactly on what position?

Comment: Upon reflection, I think I could do without the date here. However, when I use your modified code; it compiles, but the pdf file cannot be opened. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelDykes seems to be a problem of sync between your editor and your pdf viewer. Are you able to open the pdf file if you go to the folder where it resides and manually open it with your viewer?

Comment: No, when I go to the folder where the file resides, and attempt to open the pdf file, it opens; but all I get is a blank file. Earlier today I have been using my editor to produce pdfs with no problem, however...

Comment: @MichaelDykes And the problem appears with the *exact* (without additions) same code I posted?

Comment: yes, though I do have a few more commands in my preamble

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4701/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-michael-dykes)

Comment: @MichaelDykes then probably those commands are producing the problem. Try with a fresh new document with only my code *exactly as it is* (without any additions) and see if it works. Please report the result. We can continue this discussion in a chat room (the link is in the previous comment).